# Typescript nested switch alternatives

Tags: javascript, typescript, switch-statement

I have various outputs for a variety of combinations of 3 different variables.  The best solution I can come up with is nested switch statements.  I was simply wondering is there a more efficient/elegant solution that I should be using instead?   An example of what I mean can be seen below:

```
function getPaintDefectSeverity(manufacturer: string, model: string, color: string) : String {
  switch(manufacturer){
    case 'FORD': case 'BMW':
      switch(model){
        case 'puma': case 'ranger': case 'escape': case 'x3': case 'x7':
          switch(color){
            case 'red': case 'yellow': 
               return 'full paint defect'
            default: 
               return 'no paint defect'
          }
       default
         return 'no paint defect'
       }
    case 'RENAULT': case 'SEAT': 
       switch(model){
         case 'clio': case 'ibiza': 
            return 'full paint defect'
         case 'megane':
            return 'partial paint defect'
         default: 
            return 'no paint defect'
        }
    case 'AUDI':
         switch(color){
           case 'blue': 
              return 'full paint defect'
           default: 
              return 'no paint defect' 
          }
    default
      return 'no paint defect'
    }
```

Obviously this is only a sample but my question is, is having so many nested switch statements necessarily bad?  Any advice / guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of this function? Is this meant to represent some business logic? Or meant to encode some data?

Comment: a common OO pattern for this is polymorphism, see https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Answer (score 1):

If there are a relatively small number of things with a paint defect, and everything else is fine, you can use a lookup table or two. Something like this:

```js
const paintDefectsByModel = {
  'RENAULT.clio': 'full',
  'RENAULT.megane': 'partial'
  // ...
};

const paintDefectsByModelAndColor = {
  'FORD.ranger.red': 'full',
  'FORD.ranger.yellow': 'full',
  // ...
};

function getPaintDefectSeverity(manufacturer: string, model: string, color: string) : string {
  const modelKey = `${manufacturer}.${model}`;
  let paintDefect = paintDefectsByModel[modelKey];
  if (paintDefect !== undefined) {
    return `${paintDefect} paint defect`;
  }

  const modelColorKey = `${manufacturer}.${model}.${color}`;
  paintDefect = paintDefectsByModelAndColor[modelColorKey];
  if (paintDefect !== undefined) {
    return `${paintDefect} paint defect`;
  }

  return 'no paint defect';
}
```